# Have anyone ever made a study to examine the benefits of a JIT compilers?

Tags: compilation, jit

### Please don't make this into another war on whether or not JIT is better or worse than static compilation.

There has been more than plenty of religious was over statically compilation versus JIT-compilation. Personally, I'm swayed towards static compilation but that's really the problem. While JIT compilation have all sort of advantages from a theoretical point of view, I have yet to see any proof that those advantages are possible to realize -- i.e. as far as I can tell, the advantages will remain theoretical only. As far as I can tell, nobody has every made a study to gauge the current state and all we can do is use our biased guesses and dig our trenches even deeper, with yet another load of benchmarks where one group of languages is misused or is just plain irrelevant.

To answer the question, I really need two (or three) questions answered:

1. Has anyone ever made a credible study to examine the state of JIT compilers
2. Has anyone ever made a credible study that examines the state of static compilers
3. Has anyone ever made a credible study comparing the results of a study of the state of JIT compilers and a study of static compilers

Recent studies are massively more valuable than any study that's just a few years old.

A direct comparison is probably not doable, but just having two real studies with real emperical evidence would be nice; I realize that this is probably impossible to achieve, at least to a degree where most people would agree with the result. I am aware of the [benchmarking game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/) and I suspect that's the closest we have or ever will have to a real study.

Comment: What do you mean "a study to examine the state of XX languages"? What state? What is there to study? Can you really treat all JIT/compiled language implementations the same way?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No. And that's why I suspect it's impossible.

Comment: Notice that you don't exactly define what JIT compilation is, and you don't tell exactly what kind of benefit you care about.

Answer (score 0):

There are no [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) *languages*, but there are many JIT *language implementations*.

A programming language is a *specification* (of that language) in some technical report (generally written in English).

A good example of programming language specification is [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) (some variant of Scheme). You can find both JIT-compiled and interpreted (and [AOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation)-compiled also) implementations of that language.

Nothing in R5RS forbids (or suggests) JIT implementations of Scheme.

Even strongly compiled languages like C++11 could *in theory* be JIT-compiled. It usually is not worth the effort.

BTW, you can find JIT implementations of C (for example, tinycc). You can also find interpreters for C (or for C++). Look also into [Cling](https://root.cern.ch/cling).

You'll find several JIT-ing libraries. Look for instance into [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) and [LLVM](http://llvm.org/); they actually are not that much "just-in-time" (but they *appear* to be so, but do generate some assembler file internally; in essence, they are fast-enough AOT compilers which can practically be used as JIT-ing compilers). But [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit) is more "JIT"-y.

Actually, computers are fast enough that you could compile some thing into C, run a GCC compilation of that (into some temporary plugin), hence compiling every [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interaction to (`dlopen`-ed) C code. (FWIW, I did that in my old [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) thing).

Read also old Ungar PhD thesis on [Self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_(programming_language)). It did some kind of JIT which in some rare occasions was so slow (sometimes needed a whole day of CPU) that it could have appeared as being AOT.

Look also into [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/). It compiles to machine code every REPL interaction.

Read also J.Pitrat's blog on his [CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2016/12/bootstrapping-caia-part-i-the-initial-domain/) system.

In some ways, **JIT is only a buzzword.** (it may relate to degrees and ways of doing optimizations, in particular because it enables to do "running context" related optimizations; but read about [profile-guided optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization)).

Comment: Nitpicking. I'm pretty sure you know exactly what I mean.

Comment: No, you are confusing a language with its implementation. JIT is an implementation detail